# why is Git necessary to install Polymer-CLI

Tags: polymer, polymer-cli

Polymer's official documentation for Polymer-CLI installation instructs to "Ensure that Git is installed." Why is Git required? What if it's not my default VCS?

Doc referenced:
https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli